# Cannot add foreign key constraint on a date field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE patient(
  Name varchar(255),
  Geburtsdatum date,
  CONSTRAINT pk_patient PRIMARY KEY (Name,Geburtsdatum)
);

CREATE TABLE fake(
  Name varchar(255),
  PName varchar(255),
  PGeburtsdatum date,
  CONSTRAINT pk_fake PRIMARY KEY (Name,PName,PGeburtsdatum),
  CONSTRAINT fk_PName2 FOREIGN KEY (PName) REFERENCES patient(Name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_PGeburtsdatum FOREIGN KEY (PGeburtsdatum) REFERENCES patient(Geburtsdatum) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

This gives me the error "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint". If I remove the last constraint in the second table creation everything works. All my other foreign key constraints work exactly the same way. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you tagged a `mysql` question as `db2`. Anyway, the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) states:

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan

So add an index in the `Geburtsdatum` column:

```
CREATE TABLE patient(
  Name varchar(255),
  Geburtsdatum date,
  INDEX (Geburtsdatum),
  CONSTRAINT pk_patient PRIMARY KEY (Name,Geburtsdatum)
);
```

Comment: And I have other foreign key constraints on strings or integers and they work without indices.

Comment: Then that is against the MySQL documentation. Can you create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) in which you are creating a foreign key to a non-indexed column?

Comment: A primary key creates a unique index :) You can check that by removing `PRIMARY KEY` from any of the first 2 tables on your fiddle. The creation will fail again

Comment: But Geburtsdatum is also defined as a primary key.

Comment: No, it is a compound primary key. An index can not be used in that way. The sorting is first made on the first field and then on the second. So that order is no the same as having it the other way around.

Comment: If you are seeking an answer that will also work on DB2 as well, please indicate which platform(s) of DB2 you expect to use: z/OS, IBM i, or LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows), in which case the DB2 tag should be restored.