# MySQL - Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, key, create-table

I am trying to create 3 tables in MySQL but I receive the error code 1215.

```
CREATE TABLE LPC.ChildInformation
(
    ChildID CHAR(4),
    FirstName TEXT,
    Surname TEXT,
    Gender TEXT,
    DateOfBirth DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ChildID)
);

CREATE TABLE LPC.ChildAttendance
(
    AttendanceID CHAR(6),
    ChildID CHAR(4),
    ConfirmAttendance VARCHAR(3),
    DateAttended DATE,
    TypeOfDay VARCHAR(15),
    TypeOfTime VARCHAR(15),
    PlannedArrivalTime TIME,
    PlannedDepartureTime TIME,
    ActualArrivalTime TIME,
    ActualDepartureTime TIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (AttendanceID, ChildID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ChildID) REFERENCES ChildInformation(ChildID)
);
```

There are no issues when executing the script above - both tables are created.

When executing this script:

```
CREATE TABLE LPC.DailyAttendancePrice
(
    AttendanceID CHAR(6),
    DateAttended DATE, 
    TotalPrice DECIMAL(5,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (AttendanceID, DateAttended),
    FOREIGN KEY (AttendanceID) REFERENCES ChildAttendance(AttendanceID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DateAttended) REFERENCES ChildAttendance(DateAttended)
);
```

I then receive the error. I am unsure as to how this error occurs so any help is much appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but wasn't it so, that you can make foreign key references  only to primary keys in other tables?
In the last row, you are trying to reference to a Date not Primary key.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a similar problem on Stack before. See the link below: 
[Cannot add foreign key constraint on a date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313822/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-on-a-date-field)

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key column can reference only the left-most column of a KEY in the parent table. But your column `ChildAttendance.DateAttended` is not part of any key.

The data modeling doesn't seem to make sense. I guess you want a table that records the price of a given row in `ChildAttendance`? Why not just:

```
ALTER TABLE ChildAttendance ADD COLUMN TotalPrice DECIMAL(5,2);
```